# Is std::from_chars supposed to handle uppercase hexadecimal exponents?

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++17, libstdc++

On upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04 (amd64), I have noticed that the following code has started to give the result 1.4375 instead of the expected value 1472:

```cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <iostream>
#include <string_view>

int main()
{
    std::string_view src{"1.7P10"};
    double value;
    auto result = std::from_chars(src.data(), src.data() + src.size(), value, std::chars_format::hex);
    std::cout << value << '\n';
}
```

I get the expected result if I change the `P` character in the source to lowercase `p`. Both uppercase and lowercase work with `std::strtod`.

Is `std::from_chars` supposed to fail with uppercase exponent characters, or is this a bug in g++/libstdc++?

Command line used to compile:

```sh
g++ -std=c++17 test.cpp
```

(optimisation level appears to have no effect)

Output of `g++ --version`:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is `std::from_chars` supposed to fail with uppercase exponent
> characters, or is this a bug in g++/libstdc++?

This is a bug of libstdc++, submitted [105441](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=105441).

From [[charconv.from.chars]](https://eel.is/c++draft/charconv.from.chars), emphasis mine

> ```
> from_chars_result from_chars(const char* first, const char* last, double& value,
>                              chars_format fmt = chars_format::general);
> ```
>
> - *Preconditions*: `fmt` has the value of one of the enumerators of `chars_­format`.
> - *Effects*: The pattern is the expected form of the subject sequence in the `"C"` locale, **as described for `strtod`**, except that
>
>   - the sign `'+'` may only appear in the exponent part;
>   - if `fmt` has `chars_­format​::​scientific` set but not `chars_­format​::​fixed`, the otherwise optional exponent part shall
>     appear;
>   - if `fmt` has `chars_­format​::​fixed` set but not `chars_­format​::​scientific`, the optional exponent part shall not
>     appear; and
>   - **if `fmt` is `chars_­format​::​hex`, the prefix `"0x"` or `"0X"` is assumed.**

So in your example, `"1.7P10"` should be a valid pattern, and the result of `from_chars` should be equivalent to `strtod("0x1.7P10")`.